# How can I Parallelize the loops of the recurrence

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-3.8

I am trying to Parallelize the recurrence loops in the following code.
I need some help

```
import numpy as np
import math as math


def TT(P1, P2):
    # compute initial value R[0,0]
    R = np.zeros((P1, P2))

    # compute R[n,0] for n=1,2,...,P2
    R[0, 0] = math.sqrt(1 / P1)
    for n in range(1, P2):
        R[n, 0]=(math.sqrt((P1-n)/(P1 + n)))*(math.sqrt((3*n+2.0)/(2*n-1.0))) * R[n-1,0]

    # compute R[n,1] for n=0,1,...,P2
    for n in range(0, P2):
        R[n, 1] = (1 + ((n * (1.0 + n)) / (2.0 - P1))) * R[n, 0]

    # apply recurrence (Parallelize this section)
    # for n=0,1,...,P2 and x=2,3,...,N-1
    for x in range(2, math.floor(P1 / 2) - 0):
        for n in range(0, P2):
            b1 = (-n * (n + 2.0) - (4 * x - 1) * (x - P1 - 2.0) - x)
            lamda1 = (b1 / (x * (P1 - x)))
            lamda2 = (((x - 1.0) * (P1 - 2.0)) / (x**2 * (P1 - x)))
            R[n, x] = lamda1 * R[n, x - 1] + lamda2 * R[n, x - 2]

    return R

# Testing the function
sz=3
Tr = TT(sz, sz)
print(Tr)
```

I have read some posts; however, I couldn't implement it correctly because I am new in python. I need help please to make it work correctly.

Note that I am using python 3.8

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: make the recurrence works in parallel using multithreading or multiprocessing.

Comment: I mean, what is the problem with the code you have written so far to do this?

Comment: It has no problem. I want the recurrence section commented by "# apply recurrence (Parallelize this section)" to run in parallel

Comment: What was preventing you from doing it?

Comment: I am new in python and tried to implement it, but the problem was the loops inside the function TT. And I think it need an expert to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

You will need `multiprocessing` or `ray` (have a look at https://towardsdatascience.com/10x-faster-parallel-python-without-python-multiprocessing-e5017c93cce1), since multithreading only uses one physical core. These two libraries intend to use multiple physical cores.

You have to split your iterables and call a function multiple times, which runs:

```
for x in range(2, math.floor(P1 / 2) - 0): # but instead accepts a range, which you provide to the function
    for n in range(0, P2): # same for this line
...
```

Since `R` is a list (mutable), you can pass it on to the function and the function changes it. So there is no need for a global variable or returning anything. If it has to return something, then you would collect it all in a list.

This should be an easy task for these libraries, so I recommend starting [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/modern-parallel-and-distributed-python-a-quick-tutorial-on-ray-99f8d70369b8) or in the [docs of ray](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/index.html).

Comment: The problem is that the loops inside the function. I have tried Ray for simple function and doesn't work. could you please give example for nested loops.